# Helper Method to Iterate over data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a table of daily stock prices which contains the columns date, open, high, low, close.

In the the view I can see all the necessary data but I would like to try and create a helper method that could iterate over one column show me the contents and then create total.

I have started to create the helper with the code

```
    def pricing
    @daily_prices.each do |daily_price|
    daily_price.close
    end
```

But this is either gives me this:

```
    [#<DailyPrice id: 1, stock_id: 1, date: "2014-07-06", open: #<BigDecimal:7fd97d107328,'0.1E1',9(36)>, high: #<BigDecimal:7fd97d107148,'0.2E1',9(36)>, low: #<BigDecimal:7fd97d106e50,'0.5E0',9(45)>, close: #<BigDecimal:7fd97d106b58,'0.15E1',18(45)>, created_at: "2014-07-06 18:28:02", updated_at: "2014-07-06 18:28:02">, #<DailyPrice id: 2, stock_id: 2, date: "2014-07-06", open: #<BigDecimal:7fd97d10f000,'0.1E2',9(36)>, high: #<BigDecimal:7fd97d10ee20,'0.12E2',9(36)>, low: #
```

or only show me the most recent price.

such as 1.0

Can anybody please point in the right direction for this as I'm struggling to get my head around creating methods and then showing them in the view.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Have you considered using a [partial template](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for this? It sounds like it would be more appropriate than a helper method.

Comment: I have created a partial of the pricing which is used elsewhere in the app but I would like to be able to pull out pricing data so that I can manipulate it to get totals, averages etc and I thought the best way to do this would be a helper.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to show? you can use an example, like "I have 10 prices of the day, I want to see in first column: price, second: stock name ; last row: total AND averages", etc.

Comment: At the moment in my view I have prices listed by date showing open, high, low, close. The list of prices can run to several hundred records long i.e. prices per day over months. What I would like to be able to do is to sum all the "close" prices "1.45" + "3.78" etc and produce a total which I then expand on to create averages and other data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean summarise all values?

May be you can calculate it in controller

```
@daily_prices = DailyPrice.where(...).to_a
@totals = {
  close: @daily_prices.map(&:close).sum,
  open:  @daily_prices.map(&:open).sum,
  high:  @daily_prices.map(&:high).sum
}

# in view
= "Total is #{@totals[:close]}"
```

Or simply do it in view

```
= @daily_prices.map(&:close).sum
```

Or make a helper

```
def total_close(daily_prices)
  value = 0.0
  @daily_prices.each do |daily_price|
    value += daily_price.close
  end
  return value
end
```

Comment: Yes I would like to summarise all values. I think that it would be best to create a helper as I can then expand on it to further manipulate the pricing data.